# Passing user_id from back-end to client-side with Segment Analytics.NET and Mixpanel

Tags: .net, mixpanel, segment-io

I am using C# .NET, AngularJS and other technology that are quite loosely coupled. I need to implement Segment and Mixpanel. I have implemented Alias and Identify in the back-end upon registration and login respectively. I even put Track, Page calls where required.

I need to pass user_id to client side on login to pass this value with each event as it is required in the documentation. This ([How do I connect Segment.io server and client side events to the same anonymous user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377565/how-do-i-connect-segment-io-server-and-client-side-events-to-the-same-anonymous)) is quite close to what I need, and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here was that I need anyway to pass userId for Identify call on login to both back-end and front-end libraries. It should be regardless of where Alias is call. That is in accord with Segment Support responses.